# unzip preserving softlinks on busybox

Tags: linux, busybox

I have a zip with a binary library compiled by the 3rd party, which I want to install on busybox based docker image as a part of CI pipeline. When I unzip the library the soflinks to the specific .so files are not preserved and appear as ascii files. However, when I unzip the same archive on Ubuntu all soflinks are preserved as expected.
Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: Can you add to your question the full unzip command and also the filesystem type of the target directory on BusyBox (probably `stat --file-system --format=%T <directory>`)? Also, by "softlink", do you mean symlink (symbolic link)?

Comment: @bitinerant just use `unzip somefile.zip` might reproduce the scene, for my case, I'm unzipping sonar-linux.zip